# How to read local file via FileReader and file name

Tags: javascript, html, file, local, filereader

in html5 there is a class FileReader. All examples on the internet, e.g. [FileReader examle](http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/open-a-local-file-with-javascript.html), show how to deal with a file dialog, i.e. user click on button and pop-up window appear to allow to select a file from a file system. I want to do something similar but without file dialog. Let's say I have a server and I rely on templates. In templates I can create any hidden input and I want to read a file from an input value, e.g.

```
// html code snippet (created by a server via template engine)
<input type="hidden" id="file-a" value="somefile.txt" />
<button onclick="MyFunction()">Read</button>
```

Now, in javascript I want to define `MyFunction` which will read my file from hidden input tag and call FileReader API. The action will happen when someone will click on defined button in HTML code.

Comment: Where is "somefile.txt"?  If you are asking if you can read a file from the user's local machine without going through the file open dialog, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you need to know:

1. FileReader will read from the client's computer, NOT the server which is hosting the HTML page.  I don't think this is what you're looking for based on the fact you're looking for templates.  People visiting your site are not going to have the templates on their computer, unless you gave them to them.
2. You probably want to fetch() the resources from the web server.  This will allow you to do this dynamically and asynchronously.  This will require a web server capable of serving up the files in the hidden input.  Furthermore, you may not even need a hidden input as all it does is hold a hard-coded string of a filename.

If you are looking to use fetch(), I would encourage you to read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

If you still insist on using the FileReader API to read a template from the client's computer, you'll have to do some weird stuff (as it is not designed for this purpose).  NOTE: this behaviour may be perceived as malicious due to the fact that you're hiding the file reading from the user.

1. You could create an input[type=file] that is hidden by CSS
   (style='display:none')
2. add an onchange event handler to trigger
   your MyFunction
3. update the value of the input to the filename you
   want, which triggers the onchange

See documentation on [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications), dynamically adding a change listener